# Maximum length of object name in HDF5?

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I am reading an HDF5 file in Fortran and don't know the object (group) names *a priori*. So, I'm using the following code snippet to extract that info:

```
CALL H5Gn_members_f(group_id, groupName, nlinks, error)
do ilink = 0, nlinks-1
  CALL H5Gget_obj_info_idx_f(group_id, groupName, ilink, objName, H5G_GROUP_F, error)
enddo
```

Here, I've defined

```
character(len=100) :: objName
```

with the arbitrary length of 100. However, I have no guarantee that the object name is 100 characters or less. So, my actual question:

**Is there a maximum length for object names in HDF5?**

Comment: @francescalus Not exactly. My question isn't about uncertain size of a string stored in a dataset, but the _name_ of the dataset, itself.

Comment: I now parse it correctly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific maximum found in the HDF5 documentation, except for the maximum header size (the header contains all metadata about an HDF5 object).

The limit is 64kB, see the question "Is there an object header limit and how does that affect HDF5 ?" at https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/limits.html

That puts the maximum name length, in principle, to about that value.

You can specify a default maximum length that is large, as you have done, and do some error checking. I'll check in the source code of HDF5 to see whether there are specific limits.

EDIT: The function `H5Gget_obj_info_idx_f` truncates the name to the length of the character variable that is passed in. You can check afterwards with the regular name query that the name is valid.

EDIT2: This mailing list message by a person working with the HDF group confirms this, as of 2010. https://lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2010-September/003662.html